# Why is so easy for "Anonymous User" to make spam-edits?

Tags: discusión

Since I earn the privilege, I have been taking part in the review process. I haven't done this for long (maybe two weeks) but the review I see the most is a **suggested edit** which is just spam, vandalism or and ad.

It usually completely changes an answer from its original and rightful content to something like "Hey, this is great, but check my site www.blablabla.com" or similar. Author seems to be just "anonymous aser".

I know that a user doesn't need that much reputation to suggest edits, but I'm intrigued with the regularity of these spam-edits. I'm aware that probably there are a lot more I don't see, since they get review (and rejected) by other users.

So, overall I can't complain about the review process of the site. I can only say it is working well and as it was designed (with users with enough privileges taking care of these administrative tasks).

What I wonder is if there is any way of IDing this or these individual(s) and do something else about the matter. First, I don't understand how a user can be "anonymous" unless that's the displayed name of the account. Second, is there a better way to deal with users who use their "suggest edit" privilege to spam the site than just keep rejecting their edits?

Edit: I just deleted another of this spam-reedits. It seems that the user is unidentified, not one that has chosen "anonymous user" as his display name, as I suggested before. So, how cana a user remain anonymous and why do they have enough privileges to edit? Could they reach a point when they could directly edit instead of suggest edit and randomly change answers to place their spam?